# SQL Server : issue using self joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi guys I have this problem at school :

There is a table called `clientProjectDetail` it has the following columns

```
Clientid, ClientName, ProjectName
```

within `Corp` database.

Each client can have an access to one OR more projects. Write a SQL query to return multiple `ProjectNames` next to the `Clientnames` as a single comma-separated list. I can't really figure this out been at it for a couple hrs now... Thanks to anyone who could share some insight

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? You'll need to show us what you have tried so we know what will help you, or at least go into _much_ greater detail as to where you're stuck. If you can edit your question for clarity, please flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT distinct c1.Clientid, 
  c1.ClientName,
  LEFT(projects , LEN(projects)-1) projects 
FROM clientProjectDetail c1
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT c2.ProjectName + ', '
  FROM clientProjectDetail c2
  where c1.Clientid = c2.Clientid
  FOR XML PATH('')
) m (projects)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d802c/3)

Comment: Thank You very much, I'm going to play around some more and see what else I can do. Is there a resource you recommend for sql/tsql related material ? In addition to School material I've completed VTC querying. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2069183 the MSDN Books Online is a good resource.

Comment: By the way, welcome to StackOverflow. If any of the answers to your questions are helpful, then be sure to accept the answer via the check mark to the left of it. If will help future visitors and you will get site rep for accepting. See [How to Accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanks...I Have just one more question for the code you gave - what does "m (projects)" mean?

Comment: @user2069183 the `m` is the alias for the subquery and the `projects` is the name of the columns being returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Play around this query: (STUFF deleted first comma and FOR XML PATH('') helps you to concat text to single line)

```
SELECT Clients.ClientName, 
       Projects = STUFF(
             (
                SELECT ', ' + clientProjectDetail.ProjectName
                FROM clientProjectDetail 
                WHERE clientProjectDetail.Clientid = Clients.Clientid
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, '')
FROM clientProjectDetail AS Clients
```

Comment: Oh wow! that's exactly what I needed...I was about to ask about the XML Path however you answered it. Thank you guys! I'm going to play around with this stuff some more! Also is there a resource you guys recommend to go over ? So far I did the VTC querying videos on the side in addition to my regular school related material.

Comment: You can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022424/recommended-book-for-sql-server-query-optimisation